# what happens if the bootstrap.servers is down when trying to produce a message in apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a kafka cluster with 1 zookeeper (zk1), 3 brokers(bk1, bk2, bk3) and 1 schema registry(sr1). Now my question is, what happens if I specify the **bootstrap.servers = bk1** and that particular broker is down at that time but the other two brokers bk2 and bk3 are up and running,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the producer will log exceptions stating it cannot connect. Bootstrap requests will only go to the listed address(es)

You should generally always give a minimum of 3 bootstrap addresses, across failure domains (such as availability zones, or server racks)